# can't figure out how to specicfy background url webpage

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to take an image and have it repeated across the top of my webpage but i can't even get it to display.  i can't figure out how to specify the url correctly.

i needed single quotes around the website name.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
html { 
  background: url(fromthehartle.freeservers.com/images/CatTopBorder.gif) no-repeat center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}

body { 
 color: white; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<p>sample text</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: URLs start with `http://` or `https://` (or a few other things that are unlikely to be relevant in this case). Voting to close as off-topic because the problem is, essentially, a typo.

Comment: Covering up the background image with a white background on the body won't help either.

Comment: @Quentin the webserver with the asset at that URL isn't configured to support https. that being said, i updated my answer to reflect a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get your GIF to show, could be because it's not over https. I reuploaded the image on a server that supports https. You need to remove the color white from the body otherwise you won't be able to see your text

```html
<html> 
<head>
    <style>     
        html {
            background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/bK2yczN/cat.png");
            background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>
</head>  
<body> 
    <p>sample text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But you _actually_ added `"` around it and used a protocol. Thats what fixed it, not the HTTPS thing, as images are fine either way - just not encrypted on one vs the other.

Comment: @somethinghere the image was not displaying even with the ""

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.header { 
   background-image: url("http://fromthehartle.freeservers.com/images/CatTopBorder.gif");
   height:100px;
}

body { 
 color: white; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='header'>

<p>sample text</p>

</body>
</html>
```